# Angular dynamically load content in popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to dynamically load content in popover.
Here is my code:

```
<span za-popover-deferred rel="someUrl">popover</span>



angular.module('app').directive('zaPopoverDeferred', function ($http) 
{
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {rel: '@'},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).bind('click', function() {
        $http.get(attrs.rel).then(function(data) {
          var options = { content: data.data, placement: "top", html: true };
          $(element).popover(options);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

But popover open only by second click. And on the close - ajax request send again.